# Difference between asynchronous execution and synchronous workflow on a different thread

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, delegates, task

Mike Rouses in recent [MS devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-delegate-begininvoke-calls-for-net-core/?utm_source=vs_developer_news&utm_medium=referral) writes that:

> All delegates expose BeginInvoke and EndInvoke APIs, so there’s no guarantee  that the work is actually done asynchronously (BeginInvoke may just invoke a  synchronous workflow on a different thread).

I conceptually understand what this means: this different, still synchronous, thread may be blocked waiting for some operation to finish (e.g.: network query/disc access).

Is my understanding correct?

Is there other reason to have this distinction?

Comment: FWIW, I believe you are correct that this is the key point.

Comment: It strikes me that you could comment on that post and get the author to clarify bits which are unclear to you.